# Internet access in virtual machines in virtual box

Tags: virtualbox

Is it possible to get internet access and a unique ip address as well in kali linux Vm. If yes,  then what would be the networking configuration?

Comment: Yes it is but you probably need to be more specific about what you want, to get a useful answer.

Comment: What do you mean by unique IP? As for what you can: [Manual Chapter 6.2. Introduction to networking modes](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#networkingmodes)

Comment: I mean that when I set network adapter to NAT then my both VMs acquire same ip address but I didn't want this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, just make sure you set the network adapter as bridged, not as NAT, and the VM will become part of your network, getting its IP and internet access from the router (or whatever does DHCP and routing)

Comment: Note that while this works fine at home, many work place networks are configured to detect multiple MACs behind one network jack and deny access.  Or whitelist known MACs only, etc.

Comment: Is setting network adapter as bridged will be safe? As i don't want outside world have access to my virtual machine

Comment: As long as you don't open ports on your router that route traffic to your VM, the only way a hacker can gain access, is if they are either able to connect to your network (VPN, wifi, etc) or hack one of your other systems, this is perfectly safe.

Comment: For internet access I am using a wired connection  (Ethernet). Is it still safe for bridged adapter?

Comment: Yes. The kind of connection doesn't matter. Either through cable or wifi, it still connects to a router so the same statement as above applies, if the router does not forward ports to the VM, there is no way for a hacker to get access unless they somehow get access to any point inside your network, in which case they would likely be able to get in your VM anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Without more details, it’s very hard to explain what you want.

Virtual box creates a virtual machine environment on top of your host operating system. It has several options for how to configure networking.

If you select bridged networking, then your virtual machine is effectively on the same LAN or Wi-Fi as your host with different/Unique IP. It will talk to an external DHCP server and get external information.

If you select ‘shared’ networking, then your host will provide a virtual LAN for the VM to reside on, with the host providing routing and NAT services to the outside world. Your host will also provide DHCP services on the virtual LAN.

And then, it gets complicated…

Comment: My main query is that for my KALI LINUX VM I set adapter 1 to NAT and adapter 2 to host-only network but still unable to got internet access though it gave kali a unique ip address. What to do??

Comment: why are you trying to setup different adapter mode for both machines? Is there any specific purpose? By the way, the above issue can occur because of number of reasons like host config issue OR virtual machine settings so if you tell us what you are trying to achieve then maybe we can tell you a better alternative.

Comment: For pentesting in a safer environment. My both machines are namely kali linux and Win xp.

Comment: Simply use bridge mode for both machines. They'll get unique identities and safer for your home network!

Comment: thanks, it worked for win xp but still kali hasn't it's ip address  and none of them have internet access. Just different ip address can also be achieved by configuring adapter to 'host-only network' i tried that and both machines have different ip address but what about internet access??

Comment: Try this for Kali in terminal: 
`vi /etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf`
Change false to true
And then run this command
`service network-manager restart`

Comment: And try to set network mode to 'Nat' and then make sure "cable/wifi is connected" in advance settings. (Just to test, if your internet is working)

Comment: i did this but nothing worked..

Comment: Then there must be a problem with your Virtual Box settings and I would recommend you to re-install virtual box and virtual machines (as this won't take more than an hour or 2 on average machine) And you don't need to play with network settings. With default settings your virtual machine will have internet access and safe to use as well. Lastly, if you want to play with network settings then read manual here [Virtual Box Network Hardware](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html)

Comment: I know,  by default network adapter is NAT and with NAT both machines can access internet easily but will have same ip address. But I want both things internet access as well as different ip address.

Comment: I guess you have messed with settings by trying different things. So, just set adapter mode to Bridged after fresh installation. This will fix your problem!